# Comparar valores tipo char

Tags: java

Estoy creando un setter que evalue el parámetro de entrada "sexo". En este sentido, si el parámetro de entrada no es 'm', 'f', 'M' o 'F' tiene que devolver un error. En caso contrario devuelve siempre el sexo en minúscula.

Hasta el moment he hecho lo siguiente:

```
public void setGender(char gender){

if (gender!='f' || gender!='m' || gender !=Character.toUpperCase('f') || gender!= Character.toUpperCase('m')) {
    System.out.println("[ERROR] Athlete's gender must be 'f','F','m' or 'M'");
}else{
    this.gender = Character.toLowerCase(gender);
}
}
```

Sin embargo, estoy obteniendo el siguiente warning:

```
Condition 'gender!='f' || gender!='m' || gender !=Character.toUpperCase('f') || gender!= Character.toUpperCase(...' is always 'true'
```

Cuál es la razón?

Comment: La condición que pones en el `if` se cumple siempre. La única manera de que no se cumpla es que `gender` sea `m`, `f`, `M` y `F` a la vez, lo cual es imposible. Reemplaza los `||` por `&&`. También puedes poner directamente `F` y `M` en lugar de aplicar el `toUpperCase` a `f` y `m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La advertencia se produce por el operador `||` que evalúa cada condición hasta que una se cumpla, la solución es usar `&&` para que trate todas las condiciones como un todo.

Adicional a eso se pueden usar solo dos condiciones si se compara todo usando mayúsculas:

```
public void setGender(char gender) {

    if (Character.toUpperCase(gender) != 'F' && Character.toUpperCase(gender) != 'M') {
        System.out.println("[ERROR] Athlete's gender must be 'f','F','m' or 'M'");
    } else {
        this.gender = Character.toLowerCase(gender);
    }
}
```